# Can't use reverse portrait orientation without "Auto-Rotate Screen" enabled

Tags: android, android-orientation, portrait

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to programmatically set the screen orientation to reverse portrait.

#### Problem

The request to change the screen orientation only works for orientations other than reverse portrait.

#### What I've Tried

- Enabling the system-wide "Auto-Rotate Screen" setting seems to allow reverse portrait mode. However, I don't want the app to require that this be enabled in order to work .
- Both `setOrientation` and the use of a system dialog to change the orientation. The problem occurs regardless of which method is used.

#### Other info

I'm developing with a Sony Xperia M (Android 4.1.2).

Comment: I encountered this problem today, to make it work, either auto-rotate needs to be on or currently in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in xml in the manifest file using :

```
android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"
```

The similar effect programmatically:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
```

More on this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT).

Another approach could be to set the rotation of the root layout to 180 degrees. How ever it doesnot rotate the actionbar.

```
android:rotation="180"
```

Comment: I'm wanting to do it programmatically, so hard-coding it in the manifest isn't suitable. `setRequestedOrientation` doesn't do it unless "Auto-Rotate Screen" is enabled.

Comment: @Sam updated my answer does rotation work for you? I tested it in mine except for actionbar everything works.

Comment: I'm wanting something that will change the phone orientation (including the action bar), so that doesn't sound suitable for what I'm working on. Perhaps the problem I'm experiencing is just related to my phone's firmware.

Comment: Onscreen keyboard also doesn't rotate using the rotation approach. Other than that, it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` to enable orientation in all 4 orientations, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730827/how-to-disable-landscape-mode)

**EDIT:**

Turning 'auto-rotate' off forces the orientation to 'portrait' mode. I am unaware of any way around this without using the manifest.

If auto-rotate is on then initializing the app in 'fullsensor' mode and then changing to 'reverse portrait' based on configuration changes or screen orientation changes will rotate your app to that mode.

Comment: [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation) says this mode will use the sensor to set the screen orientation, but I want it fixed in reverse portrait mode.