# How to disable landscape mode?

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

i'n my application i have Fragment's in a viewPager i know how to disable the landscape from manifest and from java like :

```
            android:configChanges="orientation"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"

////////////////////////////////
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    (setContent.....)
```

but if i hold my device in landscape mode and then i running the application the application load in landscape and the portarti mode not working. why is that?

Ok i figure it out my bad:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

I forget to delete this line

Comment: add   android:screenOrientation="landscape"   in all activity of your app

Comment: i did it. at the first time. and not working if i rotate the device before the app loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the AndroidManifest.xml file add this
android:screenOrientation="portrait"

to all the activities !! Thats all !!

Answer (score 4):

`android:screenOrientation="landscape"` is **one side landscpe**

`android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` is **both side landscape**

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` is  **one side portrait**

`android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` is **both side portrait**

`android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` is **all 4 sides**

`android:screenOrientation="sensor"` is **one side landscape and one side potrate**

Comment: I know that but it my application it doesn't work i think is beacuse my viewPager or fragment's